# Sort rows and columns of matrix by permuting

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sorting, matrices

I am trying to sort square matrix of size $N$ by $\textbf{only permuting}$ rows and columns, such that row appear in increasing (left to right) while columns appear in decreasing order (top to bottom).

Edit: all elements are distinct positive integers.

My approach was to find smallest and put it at $A_{11}$, then second at $A_{22}$ and so on until whole matrix is attained.

But question I am trying to solve require $O(N^2)$ complexity. Also i have feeling that it might require some tweaking with data structure used for storing during run of algorithm, otherwise it will not possible to get desired complexity.

Comment: Not every matrix you can sort. Take for example the two-by-two identity matrix. Its not sorted, and no matter what permutation you do, there will be one row and one column that isn't sorted

Comment: I edited my question and identity matrix can't be in consideration. Thanks for hint.